# primefaces treetable

Tags: primefaces, treetable

i'm very new to primefaces. i create a treetable, all item get from database. my problem is if i select a child item, the actual selected is parent item, so then i cannot make operation on child item. here is my treetable code

```
<p:treeTable id="treeTable" value="#{aZoningController.root}" var="zonning" >
   <p:column style="text-align: left; width: 93%"> 
       <f:facet name="header"> 
      #{lbl.aZoning_pokok}
       </f:facet> 
       <h:outputText value="#{zonning.nama}" /> 
   </p:column>
   <p:column style="text-align: center; width: 5%"> 
       <f:facet name="header"> 
      #{lbl.aZoning_kod}
       </f:facet> 
       <h:outputText value="#{zonning.kod}" /> 
   </p:column>
   <p:column style="vertical-align: text-top">
       <p:menuButton value="" styleClass="mb">   
      <p:menuitem value="Update" oncomplete="confirmation.show()" process="@this" update=":actionForm:actionDialog" icon="ui-icon-document-b">
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{zonning}" target="#{aZoningController.selectedNode}" /> 
      </p:menuitem>
      <p:menuitem value="Delete" oncomplete="confirmation.show()" process="@this" update=":myform:confirmDialog" icon="ui-icon-trash">
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{zonning}" target="#{aZoningController.selectedNode}" /> 
      </p:menuitem>
       </p:menuButton> 
   </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

and i'm populate the tretable using this

```
public TreeNode getRoot() {
   root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
   List<aZoning> zon = ejbFacade.getRoot();
   for (aZoning z : zon) {
       TreeNode zonning = new DefaultTreeNode(z, root);
       createNode(z.getId(), zonning);
   }
   return root;
}

private TreeNode createNode (String idParent, TreeNode parent) {
   TreeNode node = null;
   List<aZoning> zonning = ejbFacade.getZonning(idParent);
   for (aZoning z : zonning) {
       node = new DefaultTreeNode(z, parent);
       createNode(z.getId(), node);
   }
   return node;
}
```

Please advice me

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{zonning}" target="#{aZoningController.selectedNode}" />
```

This sets the value of zonning to the selectedNode property of your aZoningController class. Instead of zonning, try setting the value that you need when the menuItem is selected. zonning is the value of the parent node, which is causing the issue.